# Prevent truncating of the box-shadow by "overflow: hidden" without paddings

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why I don't accept the [padding solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33949075/4818123) of [CSS overflow: hidden cuts shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949013/css-overflow-hidden-cuts-shadow) question is **the paddings are the geometry and the box-shadow is the decoration; the decoration must not force the changing of geometry**.

### The conflict situation example

Suppose we have two themes for `button` component: with shadows and without shadows. To adapt the second theme with paddings, we need:

1. To interfere the geometry settings
2. To know the size of shadows.

And also: what if we place the element with different shadows in one container? We need to know the each shadow size?

### About Z-Index solution

Generally, it does not work. There are the unknown for me conditions when it works so if you suggest this solution I ask you to **clarify the conditions when it works**.

### The example which you can use is solution

The `.Modal-MainSection` element has `overflow-y: scroll;` settings for the cases when modal content is too large. Because of this, the shadow of buttons has been truncated:

[image]

```html
<div class="Layout">
  <div class="Modal">
    <div class="Modal-TitleSection">
      <div class="Modal-DummyTitle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Modal-MainSection">
      <div class="Modal-DummyContent"></div>
      <div class="Modal-ButtonsBar">
        <button class="Button">Cancel</button>
        <button class="Button">OK</button>  
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.Layout {
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  height: 100%;
  background: #B2EBF2;
}

.Modal {
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  width: 220px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 12px 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  background: #42A5F5;
}

.Modal-TitleSection {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.Modal-DummyTitle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #1976D2;
}

.Modal-MainSection {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.Modal-DummyContent {
  height: 140px;
  background: #1976D2;
}

.Button {
  border: none;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 4px #FFA726;
}

.Button + .Button {
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.Modal-ButtonsBar {
  margin-top: 12px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ow8feng1/)

Also, assume that the buttons bar is the **custom content**. It means be does not know at advance when developing the modal component will be the buttons bar or no and which buttons will be.

Comment: the logical solution is to add margin to your button equal to shadow. I don't see how you can do differently

Comment: @TemaniAfif, it means "we reached the limit of CSS power" :(

Comment: most likely ...